# return word containing regexp @ sign

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, replace, autocomplete

I have a function which autocompletes a username when they start typing with @ (kind of like instagram)
When you type an @ a list of users appears and the user can click on an item/user "ex: @User1" in the list and the script autocompletes the @ with the username in the textarea "ex: @User1".

The first replacement goes wel "ex: @User1". But when the user types the second @ (and not a first letter yet) and the list appears again and then clicks on a different item/user in the list, the chosen item/user "ex: @User2" gets added within the first @ in front of the first suggestion "ex: @User2User1". But on the otherhand if the user types the second @ WITH a first letter and THEN clicks on the item/user in the list the replacement goes well.

[Link to codepen sample](http://codepen.io/sjerd/pen/ByyQvd)

this is my current function :

```
var string = $scope.searchParam;
var pattern = /@\b.+?\b/g;
$scope.match = string.match(pattern)
if($scope.match){
    value = $scope.match.pop();
    console.log('match')

}else{
    console.log('was undefined');
    var pattern = /@/g;
    var found = string.match(pattern)
    console.log(found +' is value');
    if(found.length > 0){
        value = found.pop();
    }
}

string = string.replace(value, '@'+suggestion);

console.log('oke');
$scope.searchParam = string;
$scope.searchFilter = string;
```

i also tried to check if it was present allready to only trigger when a character is typed after the @sign with this:

```
if(watching && typeof $scope.searchParam !== 'undefined' && $scope.searchParam !== null) {
    var string = $scope.searchParam;
    var pattern = /@\b.+?\b/g;
    $scope.match = string.match(pattern)

    if($scope.match){

        console.log($scope.match.length + 'match aantal' + $scope.i + ' i aantal');
        $scope.matches.push($scope.match);
        console.log($scope.matches);
        var found = $filter('filter')($scope.matches,$scope.match,true)
        if (!found.length) {
            $scope.i++;
        }
    }

    $scope.completing = true;
    $scope.searchFilter = $scope.searchParam;
    $scope.selectedIndex = -1;
}
```

but the matches are only a couple of letters so this array get's flooded. there are probably multiple answers to this problem and i'd like to know what you would go with in this situation.

Comment: The matches are returned as an array.  You could just use the match that's the last in the array of the input string...

Comment: yes, but @jbarker2160 returns a match and @ doesn't so (at)jbarker2160 will get replaced

Comment: they didn't work @sln

Comment: This should work `@\w*(?!.*@)`

Comment: This construct `@\b` really means `@(?=\w)`, so `@\b.+?\b` actually means `@\w+` in this context because you do not have additional anchors.

Comment: but declaring @\w*(?!.*@) as a pattern gives an error

Comment: Really, what error? It is valid regex. I hope you are adding delimiters.

Comment: noo watch this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5wep8vct/

Comment: Like I said its valid regex. `RegExp` requires at least a string as a parameter, you just put in `@\w*(?!.*@)` which isn't a string.

Comment: Fiddle this http://jsfiddle.net/hj3pujba/

Comment: am using that now @sln thx

Comment: Can you add test cases relevant to what you're trying to do? As of state, I'm not sure _what_ you expect as a solution.

Comment: wow, this is really confusing question. I read your question twice and still don't get it.

Comment: i edited, just try clicking on suggestions when mentioning multiple people and use @ with characters and the @ sign without extra characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
string = string.replace(value, '@'+suggestion);
```

If you only type `@` it will replace the **first** `@`. To avoid that, you have to match the last one:

```
string = string.replace(new RegExp(value+'$'), '@'+suggestion);
```

This will match the value only if it's at the end of the string, which is what you need.

You can check it [on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myyNdK).